# Spawn command not found

Tags: bash, shell, command, expect, spawn

I have an error trying to run a .sh file

```
line 2: spawn: command not found
": no such file or directory
bash.sh: line 3: expect: command not found
bash.sh: line 4: send: command not found
```

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn sftp -o IdentityFile=MyFile.ppk 500200243@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
expect "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.gatewayEnter passphrase for key 'MyFile.ppk.ppk':"
send "myPassword"
```

Any idea why it happens?

Comment: How did you run the script? you have have `expect` installed, and run your script like this `expect -f bash.sh` or `./bash.sh`

Comment: After the command 'whereis expect' responses with ' /bin/expect /usr/bin/expect /sbin/expect /usr/sbin/expect /usr/local/bin/expect /usr/share/man/man1/expect.1.gz
'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works OK for me (error from sftp: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Name or service not known`), though the `.sh` extension for an [expect](/questions/tagged/expect) ([tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl)) script is a little off-putting ;-)

Often when this sort of unexplainable/unpredictable behavior happens, it is because the script was edited under [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) (notepad.exe), which uses `\r\n` to delimit lines.  This plays havoc with [unix](/questions/tagged/unix)/[linux](/questions/tagged/linux) scripts, as only `\n` is expected as a line delimiter.

You can use [the `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` utilities](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_dos2uni.htm) to convert between the two formats.  As an experiment, I converted your script to "dos" format, and sure enough got a similar error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ unix2dos bash.sh 
unix2dos: converting file bash.sh to DOS format ...
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./bash.sh 
": no such file or directory
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dos2unix bash.sh 
dos2unix: converting file bash.sh to Unix format ...
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./bash.sh 
spawn sftp -o IdentityFile=MyFile.ppk 500200243@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ssh: Could not resolve hostname XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Name or service not known
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "myPassword""
    (file "./bash.sh" line 4)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: I have converted the file using the command you commented (unix2dos) i have the same error: 'bash.sh: line 9: spawn: command not found
' and i don't have permission to run ./bash.sh i have to run with sh bash.sh. Thanks and this is a great tool

Comment: @user3200493: This is not a shell script, this is an expect script; you cannot run an expect script with the `sh` command. See glenn's answer for instructions on how to make it executable (and a more appropriate file extension).

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, it is now working. I just did the next steps:
dos2unix bash.sh -> to convert .sh file to a unix file
chmod +x bash.sh -> for execution permissions
./bash.sh -> let me run the .sh file

and at the end of the script i put 'interact' command.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11):

1. that is an expect script, so ".exp" would be an appropriate file extension: `mv bash.sh sftp.exp`
2. do not launch it like `bash bash.sh` or `sh bash.sh`. Do this:

   1. make the program executable: `chmod a+x sftp.exp`
   2. launch it with `./sftp.exp` or `/path/to/sftp.exp` or move it to a directory in your $PATH and launch it just with `sftp.exp`
3. after you `send "myPassword"` you have to "hit enter": `send "myPassword\r"`
4. while developing an expect program, add `exp_internal 1` to the top.

Good luck, and come back with further questions.

Comment: After lunch ./sftp i have this error : No such file or directory

Comment: what did you do before you got this error. Please show the commands you performed.

Comment: watch out，launch it with "./sftp.exp".the  error  which is "command not found: ubantu.exp" met is because i only key sftp.exp.

Answer (score 3):

It seems /usr/bin/expect haven't been installed in your machine. So you will get 'command not found'

Use `which expect` to check, and install it to correct path.

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting the same error. it got resolved by using expect in following way:

```
DIRNAME=$(date +%F:%T)
expect_sh=$(expect -c "
spawn scp -r ABC xxx@yyy.yy.yy.yyy:/root/$DIRNAME
expect \"password:\"
send \"xxxx\r\"
expect \"#\"
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeychecking=no xxx@yyy.yy.yy.yyy
expect \"password:\"<
send \"xxxx\r\"
expect \"#\"
send \"rm -f /root/$DIRNAME/abc.txt\r\"
expect \"#\"
send \"scp -r /root/$DIRNAME/* root@zzz.zz.zz.zzz:/root/ABC/\r\"
expect \"password:\"
send \"xxxxx\r\"
expect \"#\"
send \"exit \r\"
")<b

echo "$expect_sh"
```

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you invoke the command.  Like ray said, even if you specify the environment with a bang at the top, you still have to run it using expect -f.